# SAS: PROC MEANS Grouping in Class Variable

Tags: sas

I have the following sample data and 'proc means' command.

```
data have;
input measure country $;
datalines; 
250 UK
800 Ireland 
500 Finland
250 Slovakia
3888 Slovenia
34 Portugal
44 Netherlands
4666 Austria
run;
PROC PRINT data=have; RUN;
```

The following PROC MEANS command prints out a listing for each country above. How can I group some of those countries (i.e. UK & Ireland, Slovakia/SLovenia as Central Europe) in the PROC MEANS step, rather than adding another datastep to add a 'case when' etc?

```
proc means data=have sum  maxdec=2 order=freq STACKODS;
var measure;
class country;
run;
```

Thanks for any help at all on this. I understand there are various things you can do in the PROC MEANS command itself (like limit the number of countries by doing this:

```
proc means data=have(WHERE=(country not in ('Finland', 'UK')
```

I'd like to do the grouping in the PROC MEANS command for brevity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy with a format for any PROC that takes a CLASS statement.

Simply build a format, either with code or from data; then apply the format in the PROC MEANS statement.

```
proc format lib=work;
value $countrygroup
"UK"="British Isles"
"Ireland"="British Isles"
"Slovakia","Slovenia"="Central Europe"
;
quit;

proc means data=have;
class country;
var measure;
format country $countrygroup.;
run;
```

It's usually better to have numeric codes for country and then format those to be whichever set of names is needed at any one time, particularly as capitalization/etc. is pretty irritating, but this works well enough even here.

The `CNTLIN=` option in PROC FORMAT allows you to make a format from a dataset, with FMTNAME as the value statement, START as the value-to-label, LABEL as the label.  (END=end of range if numeric.)  There are other options also, the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000063536.htm) goes into more detail.